# CRC calculation for big endian without byte swapping

Tags: lookup, swap, endianness, crc

I'm trying to calculate CRC16 with the slice by 4 method in a big endian system. So far I've achieved it by using the following code for generating the tables with `poly = 0xA001`:

```
void CreateSliceBy4Table(uint16_t crctable16[4][256], uint16_t short poly)
{
    uint16_t i;
    uint8_t j;
    uint16_t crc;
    
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        crc = i;
        
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            if ((crc & 0x1) != 0)
                crc = (crc >> 1) ^ poly;
                
            else
                crc >>= 1;
        }
        
        crctable16[0][i] = crc;        
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        crctable16[1][i] = ((crctable16[0][i] >> 8)) ^ crctable16[0][crctable16[0][i] & 0xFF];
        crctable16[2][i] = ((crctable16[1][i] >> 8)) ^ crctable16[0][crctable16[1][i] & 0xFF];
        crctable16[3][i] = ((crctable16[2][i] >> 8)) ^ crctable16[0][crctable16[2][i] & 0xFF];
    }

    return;
}
```

And the following code to perform the actual CRC calculation:

```
UINT16 SliceBy4LUT(const void * data, uint32_t length)
{
    uint16_t crc = 0;
    uint32_t temp = 0;
    uint32_t * data_ul = (uint32_t *) data;
    const uint8_t * data_ub;
    uint32_t swappedData_ul;
    
    while (length >= 4)
    {  
        swappedData_ul = (uint32_t) (((  *data_ul) >> 24)            |
                                      (((*data_ul) >> 8) & 0xFF00)   |
                                      (((*data_ul) << 8) & 0xFF0000) |
                                      ( (*data_ul) << 24)
                                    );

        temp = crc ^ swappedData_ul;
        
        crc = crctablebig[3][ temp        & 0xFF] ^
              crctablebig[2][(temp >> 8)  & 0xFF] ^
              crctablebig[1][(temp >> 16) & 0xFF] ^
              crctablebig[0][(temp >> 24) & 0xFF];

        length -= 4;
        data_ul++;
    }
    
    data_ub = (uint8_t *) data_ul;
    
    while (length > 0)
    {
        crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crctablebig[0][(crc & 0xFF) ^ (*data_ub++)];
        length -= 1;
    }
    
    return crc;
}
```

This code works well for big endian and the specific CRC16 that I'm using. However, I'm very concerned with efficiency and I don't want to do all the byte swapping in the lookup function on every iteration of the while loop.

I suspect there is a way of generating the tables differently so I don't need to do the byte swapping at runtime, but I can't figure out how to do it. The CRC for bytes `{0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3}` should give `0xA110`. To test this in a little endian system like my PC, I use the reversed array as `{0x3, 0x2, 0x1, 0x0}`.

Edit:
A better test is using more bytes so we loop twice in the while loop, like `{0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7}`. To test it in little endian I use `{0x3, 0x2, 0x1, 0x0, 0x7, 0x6, 0x5, 0x4}`.

Comment: CRC calculation assumes the first byte in a buffer is the most significant byte. The bits in  each byte may or may not be reflected. In this case, it appears the bits in each byte are reflected since the poly = 0xa001, which is the reverse of the non-reflected poly = 0x8005.

Comment: Your code doesn't even run in the first place. The two loops on an 8-bit `i` are infinite, since an 8-bit value will always be less than 256.

Comment: @MarkAdler you're right. I introduced that bug when I cleaned out the code to post here, it is fixed now.

Comment: Thanks. It's usually a good idea to run the code you are going to post before posting it.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use:

```
        temp = crc ^ data_ul;
        
        crc = crctablebig[0][ temp        & 0xFF] ^
              crctablebig[1][(temp >> 8)  & 0xFF] ^
              crctablebig[2][(temp >> 16) & 0xFF] ^
              crctablebig[3][(temp >> 24) & 0xFF];
```

I didn't check to see if the original code in the question is producing the correct CRC, but the change I'm suggesting should result in the same CRC as the original code in the question.

Comment: Please see my edit. Your modification does work with the first 4 bytes, but as soon as you have to loop again when you have 8+ bytes the CRC is not correct anymore. I think it has to do with how the new 4 bytes are XOR'ed with `crc` into `temp`.

Comment: @RafaelBoy - Try comparing your CRC with an online CRC calculator. The default test string is a 9 character string "123456789", but you can test other variations. For the CRC in the question a buffer with all zeros, except the last byte = 0x80, should return 0xA001. I use [this one](http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html). For your CRC, use CRC16_ARC from that web page.

Answer (score 0):

To do it right, you'd want a table with the values shifted up to the high end of a 32-bit word (for by-four). Then you only need one byte swap of the CRC coming in, and one byte swap of the CRC going out. Instead of byte swapping every word coming from memory.

Here is code:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static unsigned short const table_byte[] = {
    0x0000, 0xc0c1, 0xc181, 0x0140, 0xc301, 0x03c0, 0x0280, 0xc241, 0xc601, 0x06c0,
    0x0780, 0xc741, 0x0500, 0xc5c1, 0xc481, 0x0440, 0xcc01, 0x0cc0, 0x0d80, 0xcd41,
    0x0f00, 0xcfc1, 0xce81, 0x0e40, 0x0a00, 0xcac1, 0xcb81, 0x0b40, 0xc901, 0x09c0,
    0x0880, 0xc841, 0xd801, 0x18c0, 0x1980, 0xd941, 0x1b00, 0xdbc1, 0xda81, 0x1a40,
    0x1e00, 0xdec1, 0xdf81, 0x1f40, 0xdd01, 0x1dc0, 0x1c80, 0xdc41, 0x1400, 0xd4c1,
    0xd581, 0x1540, 0xd701, 0x17c0, 0x1680, 0xd641, 0xd201, 0x12c0, 0x1380, 0xd341,
    0x1100, 0xd1c1, 0xd081, 0x1040, 0xf001, 0x30c0, 0x3180, 0xf141, 0x3300, 0xf3c1,
    0xf281, 0x3240, 0x3600, 0xf6c1, 0xf781, 0x3740, 0xf501, 0x35c0, 0x3480, 0xf441,
    0x3c00, 0xfcc1, 0xfd81, 0x3d40, 0xff01, 0x3fc0, 0x3e80, 0xfe41, 0xfa01, 0x3ac0,
    0x3b80, 0xfb41, 0x3900, 0xf9c1, 0xf881, 0x3840, 0x2800, 0xe8c1, 0xe981, 0x2940,
    0xeb01, 0x2bc0, 0x2a80, 0xea41, 0xee01, 0x2ec0, 0x2f80, 0xef41, 0x2d00, 0xedc1,
    0xec81, 0x2c40, 0xe401, 0x24c0, 0x2580, 0xe541, 0x2700, 0xe7c1, 0xe681, 0x2640,
    0x2200, 0xe2c1, 0xe381, 0x2340, 0xe101, 0x21c0, 0x2080, 0xe041, 0xa001, 0x60c0,
    0x6180, 0xa141, 0x6300, 0xa3c1, 0xa281, 0x6240, 0x6600, 0xa6c1, 0xa781, 0x6740,
    0xa501, 0x65c0, 0x6480, 0xa441, 0x6c00, 0xacc1, 0xad81, 0x6d40, 0xaf01, 0x6fc0,
    0x6e80, 0xae41, 0xaa01, 0x6ac0, 0x6b80, 0xab41, 0x6900, 0xa9c1, 0xa881, 0x6840,
    0x7800, 0xb8c1, 0xb981, 0x7940, 0xbb01, 0x7bc0, 0x7a80, 0xba41, 0xbe01, 0x7ec0,
    0x7f80, 0xbf41, 0x7d00, 0xbdc1, 0xbc81, 0x7c40, 0xb401, 0x74c0, 0x7580, 0xb541,
    0x7700, 0xb7c1, 0xb681, 0x7640, 0x7200, 0xb2c1, 0xb381, 0x7340, 0xb101, 0x71c0,
    0x7080, 0xb041, 0x5000, 0x90c1, 0x9181, 0x5140, 0x9301, 0x53c0, 0x5280, 0x9241,
    0x9601, 0x56c0, 0x5780, 0x9741, 0x5500, 0x95c1, 0x9481, 0x5440, 0x9c01, 0x5cc0,
    0x5d80, 0x9d41, 0x5f00, 0x9fc1, 0x9e81, 0x5e40, 0x5a00, 0x9ac1, 0x9b81, 0x5b40,
    0x9901, 0x59c0, 0x5880, 0x9841, 0x8801, 0x48c0, 0x4980, 0x8941, 0x4b00, 0x8bc1,
    0x8a81, 0x4a40, 0x4e00, 0x8ec1, 0x8f81, 0x4f40, 0x8d01, 0x4dc0, 0x4c80, 0x8c41,
    0x4400, 0x84c1, 0x8581, 0x4540, 0x8701, 0x47c0, 0x4680, 0x8641, 0x8201, 0x42c0,
    0x4380, 0x8341, 0x4100, 0x81c1, 0x8081, 0x4040
};
    
// This code assumes that integers are stored big-endian.

static uint32_t const table_word32[][256] = {
   {0x00000000, 0xc1c00000, 0x81c10000, 0x40010000, 0x01c30000, 0xc0030000, 0x80020000, 0x41c20000,
    0x01c60000, 0xc0060000, 0x80070000, 0x41c70000, 0x00050000, 0xc1c50000, 0x81c40000, 0x40040000,
    0x01cc0000, 0xc00c0000, 0x800d0000, 0x41cd0000, 0x000f0000, 0xc1cf0000, 0x81ce0000, 0x400e0000,
    0x000a0000, 0xc1ca0000, 0x81cb0000, 0x400b0000, 0x01c90000, 0xc0090000, 0x80080000, 0x41c80000,
    0x01d80000, 0xc0180000, 0x80190000, 0x41d90000, 0x001b0000, 0xc1db0000, 0x81da0000, 0x401a0000,
    0x001e0000, 0xc1de0000, 0x81df0000, 0x401f0000, 0x01dd0000, 0xc01d0000, 0x801c0000, 0x41dc0000,
    0x00140000, 0xc1d40000, 0x81d50000, 0x40150000, 0x01d70000, 0xc0170000, 0x80160000, 0x41d60000,
    0x01d20000, 0xc0120000, 0x80130000, 0x41d30000, 0x00110000, 0xc1d10000, 0x81d00000, 0x40100000,
    0x01f00000, 0xc0300000, 0x80310000, 0x41f10000, 0x00330000, 0xc1f30000, 0x81f20000, 0x40320000,
    0x00360000, 0xc1f60000, 0x81f70000, 0x40370000, 0x01f50000, 0xc0350000, 0x80340000, 0x41f40000,
    0x003c0000, 0xc1fc0000, 0x81fd0000, 0x403d0000, 0x01ff0000, 0xc03f0000, 0x803e0000, 0x41fe0000,
    0x01fa0000, 0xc03a0000, 0x803b0000, 0x41fb0000, 0x00390000, 0xc1f90000, 0x81f80000, 0x40380000,
    0x00280000, 0xc1e80000, 0x81e90000, 0x40290000, 0x01eb0000, 0xc02b0000, 0x802a0000, 0x41ea0000,
    0x01ee0000, 0xc02e0000, 0x802f0000, 0x41ef0000, 0x002d0000, 0xc1ed0000, 0x81ec0000, 0x402c0000,
    0x01e40000, 0xc0240000, 0x80250000, 0x41e50000, 0x00270000, 0xc1e70000, 0x81e60000, 0x40260000,
    0x00220000, 0xc1e20000, 0x81e30000, 0x40230000, 0x01e10000, 0xc0210000, 0x80200000, 0x41e00000,
    0x01a00000, 0xc0600000, 0x80610000, 0x41a10000, 0x00630000, 0xc1a30000, 0x81a20000, 0x40620000,
    0x00660000, 0xc1a60000, 0x81a70000, 0x40670000, 0x01a50000, 0xc0650000, 0x80640000, 0x41a40000,
    0x006c0000, 0xc1ac0000, 0x81ad0000, 0x406d0000, 0x01af0000, 0xc06f0000, 0x806e0000, 0x41ae0000,
    0x01aa0000, 0xc06a0000, 0x806b0000, 0x41ab0000, 0x00690000, 0xc1a90000, 0x81a80000, 0x40680000,
    0x00780000, 0xc1b80000, 0x81b90000, 0x40790000, 0x01bb0000, 0xc07b0000, 0x807a0000, 0x41ba0000,
    0x01be0000, 0xc07e0000, 0x807f0000, 0x41bf0000, 0x007d0000, 0xc1bd0000, 0x81bc0000, 0x407c0000,
    0x01b40000, 0xc0740000, 0x80750000, 0x41b50000, 0x00770000, 0xc1b70000, 0x81b60000, 0x40760000,
    0x00720000, 0xc1b20000, 0x81b30000, 0x40730000, 0x01b10000, 0xc0710000, 0x80700000, 0x41b00000,
    0x00500000, 0xc1900000, 0x81910000, 0x40510000, 0x01930000, 0xc0530000, 0x80520000, 0x41920000,
    0x01960000, 0xc0560000, 0x80570000, 0x41970000, 0x00550000, 0xc1950000, 0x81940000, 0x40540000,
    0x019c0000, 0xc05c0000, 0x805d0000, 0x419d0000, 0x005f0000, 0xc19f0000, 0x819e0000, 0x405e0000,
    0x005a0000, 0xc19a0000, 0x819b0000, 0x405b0000, 0x01990000, 0xc0590000, 0x80580000, 0x41980000,
    0x01880000, 0xc0480000, 0x80490000, 0x41890000, 0x004b0000, 0xc18b0000, 0x818a0000, 0x404a0000,
    0x004e0000, 0xc18e0000, 0x818f0000, 0x404f0000, 0x018d0000, 0xc04d0000, 0x804c0000, 0x418c0000,
    0x00440000, 0xc1840000, 0x81850000, 0x40450000, 0x01870000, 0xc0470000, 0x80460000, 0x41860000,
    0x01820000, 0xc0420000, 0x80430000, 0x41830000, 0x00410000, 0xc1810000, 0x81800000, 0x40400000},
   {0x00000000, 0x01900000, 0x01600000, 0x00f00000, 0x02c00000, 0x03500000, 0x03a00000, 0x02300000,
    0x07c00000, 0x06500000, 0x06a00000, 0x07300000, 0x05000000, 0x04900000, 0x04600000, 0x05f00000,
    0x0dc00000, 0x0c500000, 0x0ca00000, 0x0d300000, 0x0f000000, 0x0e900000, 0x0e600000, 0x0ff00000,
    0x0a000000, 0x0b900000, 0x0b600000, 0x0af00000, 0x08c00000, 0x09500000, 0x09a00000, 0x08300000,
    0x19c00000, 0x18500000, 0x18a00000, 0x19300000, 0x1b000000, 0x1a900000, 0x1a600000, 0x1bf00000,
    0x1e000000, 0x1f900000, 0x1f600000, 0x1ef00000, 0x1cc00000, 0x1d500000, 0x1da00000, 0x1c300000,
    0x14000000, 0x15900000, 0x15600000, 0x14f00000, 0x16c00000, 0x17500000, 0x17a00000, 0x16300000,
    0x13c00000, 0x12500000, 0x12a00000, 0x13300000, 0x11000000, 0x10900000, 0x10600000, 0x11f00000,
    0x31c00000, 0x30500000, 0x30a00000, 0x31300000, 0x33000000, 0x32900000, 0x32600000, 0x33f00000,
    0x36000000, 0x37900000, 0x37600000, 0x36f00000, 0x34c00000, 0x35500000, 0x35a00000, 0x34300000,
    0x3c000000, 0x3d900000, 0x3d600000, 0x3cf00000, 0x3ec00000, 0x3f500000, 0x3fa00000, 0x3e300000,
    0x3bc00000, 0x3a500000, 0x3aa00000, 0x3b300000, 0x39000000, 0x38900000, 0x38600000, 0x39f00000,
    0x28000000, 0x29900000, 0x29600000, 0x28f00000, 0x2ac00000, 0x2b500000, 0x2ba00000, 0x2a300000,
    0x2fc00000, 0x2e500000, 0x2ea00000, 0x2f300000, 0x2d000000, 0x2c900000, 0x2c600000, 0x2df00000,
    0x25c00000, 0x24500000, 0x24a00000, 0x25300000, 0x27000000, 0x26900000, 0x26600000, 0x27f00000,
    0x22000000, 0x23900000, 0x23600000, 0x22f00000, 0x20c00000, 0x21500000, 0x21a00000, 0x20300000,
    0x61c00000, 0x60500000, 0x60a00000, 0x61300000, 0x63000000, 0x62900000, 0x62600000, 0x63f00000,
    0x66000000, 0x67900000, 0x67600000, 0x66f00000, 0x64c00000, 0x65500000, 0x65a00000, 0x64300000,
    0x6c000000, 0x6d900000, 0x6d600000, 0x6cf00000, 0x6ec00000, 0x6f500000, 0x6fa00000, 0x6e300000,
    0x6bc00000, 0x6a500000, 0x6aa00000, 0x6b300000, 0x69000000, 0x68900000, 0x68600000, 0x69f00000,
    0x78000000, 0x79900000, 0x79600000, 0x78f00000, 0x7ac00000, 0x7b500000, 0x7ba00000, 0x7a300000,
    0x7fc00000, 0x7e500000, 0x7ea00000, 0x7f300000, 0x7d000000, 0x7c900000, 0x7c600000, 0x7df00000,
    0x75c00000, 0x74500000, 0x74a00000, 0x75300000, 0x77000000, 0x76900000, 0x76600000, 0x77f00000,
    0x72000000, 0x73900000, 0x73600000, 0x72f00000, 0x70c00000, 0x71500000, 0x71a00000, 0x70300000,
    0x50000000, 0x51900000, 0x51600000, 0x50f00000, 0x52c00000, 0x53500000, 0x53a00000, 0x52300000,
    0x57c00000, 0x56500000, 0x56a00000, 0x57300000, 0x55000000, 0x54900000, 0x54600000, 0x55f00000,
    0x5dc00000, 0x5c500000, 0x5ca00000, 0x5d300000, 0x5f000000, 0x5e900000, 0x5e600000, 0x5ff00000,
    0x5a000000, 0x5b900000, 0x5b600000, 0x5af00000, 0x58c00000, 0x59500000, 0x59a00000, 0x58300000,
    0x49c00000, 0x48500000, 0x48a00000, 0x49300000, 0x4b000000, 0x4a900000, 0x4a600000, 0x4bf00000,
    0x4e000000, 0x4f900000, 0x4f600000, 0x4ef00000, 0x4cc00000, 0x4d500000, 0x4da00000, 0x4c300000,
    0x44000000, 0x45900000, 0x45600000, 0x44f00000, 0x46c00000, 0x47500000, 0x47a00000, 0x46300000,
    0x43c00000, 0x42500000, 0x42a00000, 0x43300000, 0x41000000, 0x40900000, 0x40600000, 0x41f00000},
   {0x00000000, 0x51c00000, 0xa1c00000, 0xf0000000, 0x41c10000, 0x10010000, 0xe0010000, 0xb1c10000,
    0x81c20000, 0xd0020000, 0x20020000, 0x71c20000, 0xc0030000, 0x91c30000, 0x61c30000, 0x30030000,
    0x01c50000, 0x50050000, 0xa0050000, 0xf1c50000, 0x40040000, 0x11c40000, 0xe1c40000, 0xb0040000,
    0x80070000, 0xd1c70000, 0x21c70000, 0x70070000, 0xc1c60000, 0x90060000, 0x60060000, 0x31c60000,
    0x01ca0000, 0x500a0000, 0xa00a0000, 0xf1ca0000, 0x400b0000, 0x11cb0000, 0xe1cb0000, 0xb00b0000,
    0x80080000, 0xd1c80000, 0x21c80000, 0x70080000, 0xc1c90000, 0x90090000, 0x60090000, 0x31c90000,
    0x000f0000, 0x51cf0000, 0xa1cf0000, 0xf00f0000, 0x41ce0000, 0x100e0000, 0xe00e0000, 0xb1ce0000,
    0x81cd0000, 0xd00d0000, 0x200d0000, 0x71cd0000, 0xc00c0000, 0x91cc0000, 0x61cc0000, 0x300c0000,
    0x01d40000, 0x50140000, 0xa0140000, 0xf1d40000, 0x40150000, 0x11d50000, 0xe1d50000, 0xb0150000,
    0x80160000, 0xd1d60000, 0x21d60000, 0x70160000, 0xc1d70000, 0x90170000, 0x60170000, 0x31d70000,
    0x00110000, 0x51d10000, 0xa1d10000, 0xf0110000, 0x41d00000, 0x10100000, 0xe0100000, 0xb1d00000,
    0x81d30000, 0xd0130000, 0x20130000, 0x71d30000, 0xc0120000, 0x91d20000, 0x61d20000, 0x30120000,
    0x001e0000, 0x51de0000, 0xa1de0000, 0xf01e0000, 0x41df0000, 0x101f0000, 0xe01f0000, 0xb1df0000,
    0x81dc0000, 0xd01c0000, 0x201c0000, 0x71dc0000, 0xc01d0000, 0x91dd0000, 0x61dd0000, 0x301d0000,
    0x01db0000, 0x501b0000, 0xa01b0000, 0xf1db0000, 0x401a0000, 0x11da0000, 0xe1da0000, 0xb01a0000,
    0x80190000, 0xd1d90000, 0x21d90000, 0x70190000, 0xc1d80000, 0x90180000, 0x60180000, 0x31d80000,
    0x01e80000, 0x50280000, 0xa0280000, 0xf1e80000, 0x40290000, 0x11e90000, 0xe1e90000, 0xb0290000,
    0x802a0000, 0xd1ea0000, 0x21ea0000, 0x702a0000, 0xc1eb0000, 0x902b0000, 0x602b0000, 0x31eb0000,
    0x002d0000, 0x51ed0000, 0xa1ed0000, 0xf02d0000, 0x41ec0000, 0x102c0000, 0xe02c0000, 0xb1ec0000,
    0x81ef0000, 0xd02f0000, 0x202f0000, 0x71ef0000, 0xc02e0000, 0x91ee0000, 0x61ee0000, 0x302e0000,
    0x00220000, 0x51e20000, 0xa1e20000, 0xf0220000, 0x41e30000, 0x10230000, 0xe0230000, 0xb1e30000,
    0x81e00000, 0xd0200000, 0x20200000, 0x71e00000, 0xc0210000, 0x91e10000, 0x61e10000, 0x30210000,
    0x01e70000, 0x50270000, 0xa0270000, 0xf1e70000, 0x40260000, 0x11e60000, 0xe1e60000, 0xb0260000,
    0x80250000, 0xd1e50000, 0x21e50000, 0x70250000, 0xc1e40000, 0x90240000, 0x60240000, 0x31e40000,
    0x003c0000, 0x51fc0000, 0xa1fc0000, 0xf03c0000, 0x41fd0000, 0x103d0000, 0xe03d0000, 0xb1fd0000,
    0x81fe0000, 0xd03e0000, 0x203e0000, 0x71fe0000, 0xc03f0000, 0x91ff0000, 0x61ff0000, 0x303f0000,
    0x01f90000, 0x50390000, 0xa0390000, 0xf1f90000, 0x40380000, 0x11f80000, 0xe1f80000, 0xb0380000,
    0x803b0000, 0xd1fb0000, 0x21fb0000, 0x703b0000, 0xc1fa0000, 0x903a0000, 0x603a0000, 0x31fa0000,
    0x01f60000, 0x50360000, 0xa0360000, 0xf1f60000, 0x40370000, 0x11f70000, 0xe1f70000, 0xb0370000,
    0x80340000, 0xd1f40000, 0x21f40000, 0x70340000, 0xc1f50000, 0x90350000, 0x60350000, 0x31f50000,
    0x00330000, 0x51f30000, 0xa1f30000, 0xf0330000, 0x41f20000, 0x10320000, 0xe0320000, 0xb1f20000,
    0x81f10000, 0xd0310000, 0x20310000, 0x71f10000, 0xc0300000, 0x91f00000, 0x61f00000, 0x30300000},
   {0x00000000, 0x01fc0000, 0x01b80000, 0x00440000, 0x01300000, 0x00cc0000, 0x00880000, 0x01740000,
    0x02600000, 0x039c0000, 0x03d80000, 0x02240000, 0x03500000, 0x02ac0000, 0x02e80000, 0x03140000,
    0x04c00000, 0x053c0000, 0x05780000, 0x04840000, 0x05f00000, 0x040c0000, 0x04480000, 0x05b40000,
    0x06a00000, 0x075c0000, 0x07180000, 0x06e40000, 0x07900000, 0x066c0000, 0x06280000, 0x07d40000,
    0x0bc00000, 0x0a3c0000, 0x0a780000, 0x0b840000, 0x0af00000, 0x0b0c0000, 0x0b480000, 0x0ab40000,
    0x09a00000, 0x085c0000, 0x08180000, 0x09e40000, 0x08900000, 0x096c0000, 0x09280000, 0x08d40000,
    0x0f000000, 0x0efc0000, 0x0eb80000, 0x0f440000, 0x0e300000, 0x0fcc0000, 0x0f880000, 0x0e740000,
    0x0d600000, 0x0c9c0000, 0x0cd80000, 0x0d240000, 0x0c500000, 0x0dac0000, 0x0de80000, 0x0c140000,
    0x15c00000, 0x143c0000, 0x14780000, 0x15840000, 0x14f00000, 0x150c0000, 0x15480000, 0x14b40000,
    0x17a00000, 0x165c0000, 0x16180000, 0x17e40000, 0x16900000, 0x176c0000, 0x17280000, 0x16d40000,
    0x11000000, 0x10fc0000, 0x10b80000, 0x11440000, 0x10300000, 0x11cc0000, 0x11880000, 0x10740000,
    0x13600000, 0x129c0000, 0x12d80000, 0x13240000, 0x12500000, 0x13ac0000, 0x13e80000, 0x12140000,
    0x1e000000, 0x1ffc0000, 0x1fb80000, 0x1e440000, 0x1f300000, 0x1ecc0000, 0x1e880000, 0x1f740000,
    0x1c600000, 0x1d9c0000, 0x1dd80000, 0x1c240000, 0x1d500000, 0x1cac0000, 0x1ce80000, 0x1d140000,
    0x1ac00000, 0x1b3c0000, 0x1b780000, 0x1a840000, 0x1bf00000, 0x1a0c0000, 0x1a480000, 0x1bb40000,
    0x18a00000, 0x195c0000, 0x19180000, 0x18e40000, 0x19900000, 0x186c0000, 0x18280000, 0x19d40000,
    0x29c00000, 0x283c0000, 0x28780000, 0x29840000, 0x28f00000, 0x290c0000, 0x29480000, 0x28b40000,
    0x2ba00000, 0x2a5c0000, 0x2a180000, 0x2be40000, 0x2a900000, 0x2b6c0000, 0x2b280000, 0x2ad40000,
    0x2d000000, 0x2cfc0000, 0x2cb80000, 0x2d440000, 0x2c300000, 0x2dcc0000, 0x2d880000, 0x2c740000,
    0x2f600000, 0x2e9c0000, 0x2ed80000, 0x2f240000, 0x2e500000, 0x2fac0000, 0x2fe80000, 0x2e140000,
    0x22000000, 0x23fc0000, 0x23b80000, 0x22440000, 0x23300000, 0x22cc0000, 0x22880000, 0x23740000,
    0x20600000, 0x219c0000, 0x21d80000, 0x20240000, 0x21500000, 0x20ac0000, 0x20e80000, 0x21140000,
    0x26c00000, 0x273c0000, 0x27780000, 0x26840000, 0x27f00000, 0x260c0000, 0x26480000, 0x27b40000,
    0x24a00000, 0x255c0000, 0x25180000, 0x24e40000, 0x25900000, 0x246c0000, 0x24280000, 0x25d40000,
    0x3c000000, 0x3dfc0000, 0x3db80000, 0x3c440000, 0x3d300000, 0x3ccc0000, 0x3c880000, 0x3d740000,
    0x3e600000, 0x3f9c0000, 0x3fd80000, 0x3e240000, 0x3f500000, 0x3eac0000, 0x3ee80000, 0x3f140000,
    0x38c00000, 0x393c0000, 0x39780000, 0x38840000, 0x39f00000, 0x380c0000, 0x38480000, 0x39b40000,
    0x3aa00000, 0x3b5c0000, 0x3b180000, 0x3ae40000, 0x3b900000, 0x3a6c0000, 0x3a280000, 0x3bd40000,
    0x37c00000, 0x363c0000, 0x36780000, 0x37840000, 0x36f00000, 0x370c0000, 0x37480000, 0x36b40000,
    0x35a00000, 0x345c0000, 0x34180000, 0x35e40000, 0x34900000, 0x356c0000, 0x35280000, 0x34d40000,
    0x33000000, 0x32fc0000, 0x32b80000, 0x33440000, 0x32300000, 0x33cc0000, 0x33880000, 0x32740000,
    0x31600000, 0x309c0000, 0x30d80000, 0x31240000, 0x30500000, 0x31ac0000, 0x31e80000, 0x30140000}
  };

static inline uint32_t swap32(uint32_t crc) {
    return
        ((crc & 0xff) << 24) +
        ((crc & 0xff00) << 8) +
        ((crc & 0xff0000) >> 8) +
        ((crc & 0xff000000) >> 24);
}

unsigned crc16arc_word32(unsigned crc, void const *mem, size_t len) {
    unsigned char const *data = mem;
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0;
    crc &= 0xffff;
    while (len && ((ptrdiff_t)data & 3)) {
        crc = (crc >> 8) ^
              table_byte[(crc ^ *data++) & 0xff];
        len--;
    }
    if (len >= 4) {
        uint32_t word = swap32(crc);
        do {
            word ^= *(uint32_t const *)data;
            word = table_word32[0][word & 0xff] ^
                   table_word32[1][(word >> 8) & 0xff] ^
                   table_word32[2][(word >> 16) & 0xff] ^
                   table_word32[3][word >> 24];
            data += 4;
            len -= 4;
        } while (len >= 4);
        crc = swap32(word);
    }
    while (len--)
        crc = (crc >> 8) ^
              table_byte[(crc ^ *data++) & 0xff];
    return crc;
}
```